# .Net Core 2.0 compatible with .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am new to .Net Core 2.X. I was writing some authentication related code in controller.And I wrote the business logic in .Net Framework 4.6 class library. When I tried referencing the .Net Framework library, my .Net Core 2.1 project started loosing all of the system, Linq references.

Then I created took a .Net Core 2.0 class library project. And when I reference it, the same happens. I could get more information or anything.

Below is the image when I referenced .Net Framework 4.6/.Net Core 2.1 proejcts.
Could anyone please tell me the reason and fix for this.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait, I just re-read your question. You shouldn't reference .NET Framework projects from .NET Core.

Comment: If a reference .Net Core 2.0 to 2.1, I am facing the same issue

Comment: I would recommend writing class libraries in .Net standard. they can be references from both core and .Net Framework.

Comment: 2.0 should not use 2.1. Upgrade everything to 2.1 if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework and .Net Core are fundamentally different enviroments, and while the for the programmer for the biggerst part everything looks the same under the hood it is not. While you can expect mose code to seamlessly be ported over to .Net Core, references and some NuGet packages wont work. Especially refering to .Net Framework specific assemblies which dont exist in .Net Core wont work.